# selecting an nth element in jQuery with $this

Tags: jquery

I have this long `li` and I want to select the last Font Awesome with `$this` to toggleClass there or if there is a better way to do it then changing on a click 
`<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></I>` into `<i class="far fa-check-circle"></I>`

```js
$("li").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
  $(this).children(".done").toggleClass("done-gold");
  $(this)("i:last").toggleClass("fas");
  $(this).children("i:last").toggleClass("far");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> 
    <span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span>
    <i class="far fa-hand-point-right"></i>
    clean up your room
    <span class="done"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Those last two obviously don't work - I don't know how to select that properly

Comment: `$(this)("i:last").toggleClass("fas")` dont work because you are missing something like `.find("i:last")`

Comment: `children()` also doesn't work as the `.fas` you want to target isn't a child of the `li`. As @CarstenLøvboAndersen says, adding `find()` is all you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$(this).find("i").last().toggleClass("fas");`

```js
$("li").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
  $(this).children(".done").toggleClass("done-gold");
  $(this).find("i").last().toggleClass("fas");
  $(this).find("span").last().css("background-color", "red");
  $(this).children("i:last").toggleClass("far");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span>
    <i class="far fa-hand-point-right"></i> clean up your room
    <span class="done">Done<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code so it's readable. You've also got an error in the `<script>`